# Custom Next.js - difference between getRequestHandler and render functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Good day,

I was surprised that I couldn't find any information on the `getRequestHandler` and `render` functions of the `next` package.

I am trying to set up a custom server and was wondering what the `render` function was actually doing or why it is even used? `getRequestHandler` clearly renders the app so why would I ever want to use render to pass in a path manually? Also, what is the point of passing in pathname and query separately?

I am clearly confused regarding the use cases of these two - in which situation would I use one or the other?

Thank you for everyone's help.

Anagni

See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 19):

**getRequestHandler vs render**

`app.getRequestHandler` returns a request handler which we can use to parse all HTTP requests. `app.render` checks if static assets need to serve. It also checks if the page requested is a blocked/internal page. After those checks pass, Next.js also use the same request handler that we will get from `app.getRequestHandler`. If we use request handler directly, we won't get those checks and run into issues which we need to handle it manually.

Here are parts of the source code that deal with custom server. I hope it make the answer a bit more clear.

```js
// next/next-server/server/next-server.ts
// This function expose a private method, which used by render 
public getRequestHandler() {
  return this.handleRequest.bind(this)
}

// render method
public async render() {
  // .... more code
  // check if server needs to handle static files
  if (
    !query._nextDataReq &&
    (url.match(/^\/_next\//) ||
      (this.hasStaticDir && url.match(/^\/static\//)))
  ) {
    return this.handleRequest(req, res, parsedUrl)
  }
  // check the requested page is a internal/blocked page
  if (isBlockedPage(pathname)) {
    return this.render404(req, res, parsedUrl)
  }

  const html = await this.renderToHTML(req, res, pathname, query)
  // Request was ended by the user
  if (html === null) {
    return
  }

  // respond with rendered HTML
  return this.sendHTML(req, res, html)

}
```

**Path & Query**

I think Next.js `query` is a bit different from URL query strings. You can have a route like this `'/a'` and pass in a query object without adding those query to your URL.

This is my best effort to answer the question. Hopefully, I can provide some help.

***Reference:***

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/next-server/server/next-server.ts